# Get user payment details when payment successfully done in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am new in woocommerce and implementing for the first time so basically, I want to get all payment and user details when the user done payment. I need because I want to store in the separate table as per our requirement. Is there any way to get details.

[image]

Comment: What payment platform are you using? ie. Stripe/PayPal, etc. Note that storing these details should be in an encrypted form and you will need to ensure the server you are running your application on is PCI compliant. https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/

Comment: I am using Paytm platform and I am storing only first name, last name, email and location details.

Comment: That stuff will be stored with the orders. Is there a reason it needs to be stored separately?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have to show all transactions in my another admin panel.

Comment: You can use Stripe for payments it gives all details you want

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after an order created you can get details of it.

The [woocommerce_payment_complete](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#122) hook is fired when the payment is completed. The only variable passed is the order id, though from that you can get the order object, and ultimately the user.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
     $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

     $user = $order->get_user();
     if( $user ){
        // do something with the user
     }

   $order_id = $order_data['id'];
   $order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
   $order_status = $order_data['status'];
   $order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
   $order_version = $order_data['version'];
   $order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
   $order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];

   $order_discount_total = $order_data['discount_total'];
   $order_discount_tax = $order_data['discount_tax'];
   $order_shipping_total = $order_data['shipping_total'];
   $order_shipping_tax = $order_data['shipping_tax'];
   $order_total = $order_data['cart_tax'];
   $order_total_tax = $order_data['total_tax'];
   $order_customer_id = $order_data['customer_id']; // ... and so on

   ## BILLING INFORMATION:

   $order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'];
   $order_billing_last_name = $order_data['billing']['last_name'];
   $order_billing_company = $order_data['billing']['company'];
   $order_billing_address_1 = $order_data['billing']['address_1'];
   $order_billing_address_2 = $order_data['billing']['address_2'];
   $order_billing_city = $order_data['billing']['city'];
   $order_billing_state = $order_data['billing']['state'];
   $order_billing_postcode = $order_data['billing']['postcode'];
   $order_billing_country = $order_data['billing']['country'];
   $order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'];
   $order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'];

   ## SHIPPING INFORMATION:

   $order_shipping_first_name = $order_data['shipping']['first_name'];
   $order_shipping_last_name = $order_data['shipping']['last_name'];
   $order_shipping_company = $order_data['shipping']['company'];
   $order_shipping_address_1 = $order_data['shipping']['address_1'];
   $order_shipping_address_2 = $order_data['shipping']['address_2'];
   $order_shipping_city = $order_data['shipping']['city'];
   $order_shipping_state = $order_data['shipping']['state'];
   $order_shipping_postcode = $order_data['shipping']['postcode'];
   $order_shipping_country = $order_data['shipping']['country'];

 }
```

You can get details like this of an order after it's payment done. Further, you can store it in your another table.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I have added your function in my theme function.php file and echo all variables but not getting any value. Can you please guide me as i don't have any knowledge in woocommerce.

Comment: Or plz try this hook,
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
  //your code
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete' );

This will do whenever you order status will be completed then it will call this function.

Comment: Or you can see above answer I have been changed the hook in it, you can try it also.

Comment: Is there any changes required in woocommerce setting to use your hook?

Comment: no, I don't think so that we need to do any changes in woocommerce settings for it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Let me try :)

Comment: This function is nothing return when user redirect to above mentioned screenshot page. function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){ ... }. I have added in my theme function.php